# Getting error "request.all is not a function", and request.param and request.params are no longer functions in AdonisJS

Tags: parameters, request, adonis.js

I want to get the request parameters from a route. More specifically, in my case I want these parameters to be sent to a function in a bound Controller.

From [older documentation](https://adonisjs.com/docs/3.2/request#_paramkey_defaultvalue) it looks like there used to be the functions for `request.param()` and `request.params()`, but I can't find the same functions in the [newer documentation](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.0/request).

When trying these functions I get something like

`request.params is not a function`

Note, the "newer" documentation I cited is 4.0, not 4.1 (which is what I am using), but when trying functions like `request.all()` from the 4.1 documentation I will get similar "is not a function" errors. I'm not sure if I'm making some mistake or if this documentation is out of date.

Answer (score 0):

After breaking down the Objects with some debug statements, ie. `Object.keys(request)` followed by `Object.keys(request.params)`, it looks like there is a "params" member, but it is an object/array, not a function. It's value can be accessed by `request.params.the_parameter` or `request.params['the_parameter']`.

The resulting code to access request parameters from the controller is as follows (I am creating a user invitation system):

routes.js

```js
// a "?" is inserted after the invite_code parameter to indicate that it is optional
Route.get('/invitation/:invite_code?', 'UserController.invitation').as('invitation')
```

MyController.js

```js
class UserController {
    async invitation({ view, request }) {

        // Pass invite code to the view so it can be injected into a form
        // (this way invite codes can be built into links, or inserted manually)
        return view.render('account.invitation', { invite_code: request.params.invite_code })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class UserController {
    async invitation({ view, request, params }) {

        // Pass invite code to the view so it can be injected into a form
        // (this way invite codes can be built into links, or inserted manually)
        return view.render('account.invitation', { invite_code: params.invite_code })
    }
}
```